# Rails best practices - Controller or model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I want to use this piece of code to retrieve a user's list of credit cards on file with Stripe to show on his profile (/users/:id)

`@stripe_cards = Stripe::Customer.retreive(self.stripe_customer_id).cards.all`

Thing is, I'm not exactly sure where (in terms of Rails best practices) it fits. My first tought is to put it in the show method of the User controller since it's not really business logic and doesn't fit in the model. I've also looked at helper methods but they seem (from my understanding) to be used strictly when toying around with HTML.

Can any of you Rails experts chime in?

Thanks!
Francis

Comment: show method of the User controller looks okay to me

Comment: I would probably put an accessor on Custom that takes a user id and returns the cards (that is, if I understand your models correctly). Then in the controller you wouldn't have to call retreieve or cards. Also, is the all necessary?

Comment: @musicnerd47 Can you please elaborate on the "accessor on Custom" you mentioned? Also, I'm using the .all right now and know that in the long run might cause problems but doubt that users might have that many valid credit cards on file :)

Comment: Right, but you shouldn't need to call "all", it should just work. Also, I meant "accessor on Customer"

Comment: Yes, I removed the .all following your advise. Also, I will look into accessors. How are they better than methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. Whenever you see an instance variable in rails (starting with a `@`), it usually is a view/controller bit of code.

```
@stripe_cards = Stripe::Customer.retreive(self.stripe_customer_id).cards.all
```

However looking at the tail end of that

```
Stripe::Customer.retreive(self.stripe_customer_id).cards.all
```

This might fit better of in a model, where you can **reuse** that same line, but have the safety of added error handling and predictable behavior. For example

```
# user.rb

def stripe_customer_cards
  Stripe::Customer.retreive(self.stripe_customer_id).cards.all
  rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError
    false # You could use this to render some information in your views, without breaking your app.
end
```

Also note the use of `self`. This usually implies use of a Rails model, because calling `self` in the controller actually refers to the controller, rendering it almost worthless, unless you really know what you are doing.

**EDIT**

To render an error message, simply write a call to redirect or render, with the `alert` option.

```
if @stripe_cards = current_user.stripe_customer_cards
  # Your being paid, sweet!
else
  # Render alert info :(
  render 'my_view', alert: 'This is an alert'
  redirect_to other_path, alert: 'Another alert'
end
```

I also like to make it a point to mention that you should not handle errors just because you can. **Don't handle errors you don't expect.** If you handle errors you don't expect it will

- Confuse users
- Make bugs in code harder to fix
- Exaggerate the time before an error is recognized

Comment: Nitpick: @ doesn't indicate a global variable, it indicates a class instance-scoped variable. Global variables start with $, and you'll (hopefully) find them only rarely in Rails apps. @@ is class-scoped (or module-scoped in some cases), analogous to a static variable in other languages.

Comment: @bwheeler96 Thanks for the great answer, I didn't consider the error handling part when I posted the question. Speaking of which, I'm not sure I understand how I could render it in my view. I use flash messages right now with Bootstrap alerts.

Comment: Error handling in the view is a long conversation, the bootstrap alert is an excellent option for **most** cases.

Comment: @bwheeler96 Thanks for your edit, much appreciated. I now have a better understanding. It raises another question though: Wouldn't I want to catch the exact error message from Stripe and display it to the user?

Comment: Francis, to answer your question, think: "What if this error occurs for an **unexpected** reason, and it's caught, would this be problematic?". If the answer is yes, don't catch the exception. You can do whatever you want with your code, I just don't want to see other developers shoot themselves in the foot.

Comment: Hi @bwheeler96, thanks for your input once again. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: No problem, I appreciate the chance to help out when I can.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend adding a virtual attribute in your `User` model:

```
# app/models/user.rb
def cards
    Stripe::Customer.retrieve(stripe_customer_id).cards.all # note the spelling of `retrieve`
end
```

Then, you'd be able to access all a users cards in the following manner:

```
user = User.first
#=> #<User id:1>

user.cards
#=> [Array of all cards]
```